# ToolTip for asp.net page. Have to display 3 tables as tooltip

Tags: c#, asp.net, uinavigationbar

And is it possible to add a ballon tool tip like the one in windows in asp.net website. I want to display 3 tables as tooltip which when I give it in a text box doesn't align and I would Like to have some ideas and suggestions about how to implement it.

1. add text to menu.

Comment: Is `uinavigationbar` a product, a custom control, what? I would imagine setting the `Text` and `ToolTip` properties, though, would do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        Menu mainmenu = new Menu();
        MenuItem NavigationMenu = new MenuItem();
        NavigationMenu.Text = "This is a text";
        NavigationMenu.NavigateUrl = "../somepage.aspx";
        mainmenu.Items.Add(NavigationMenu);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NavigationMenu.Items.Add(new MenuItem
         {
             Text= "This is my text",
             ToolTip= "This is my tooltip"
         });
```